# How to draw every possible paths from a bi-directional state machine diagram using NetworkX Library in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, path, networkx, graph-theory

I have the state machine model of a system which has some nodes(states) and some edges(transitions). Some of the transitions are bi-directional. For example, one transition from 'State_B' to 'State_C' and another from 'State_C' to 'State_B' etc. So, this is called cycles as far as I know.

Now this is the code of the state machine model:-

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

global CP_Data_In_Coupler_Connected, CP_Data_In_CPState

# Create a directed graph (DiGraph) for the state machine
G = nx.DiGraph()

# Add states to the graph
G.add_node("State_A_Standby")
G.add_node("State_A")
G.add_node("State_B")
G.add_node("State_C")

# Temporary Nodes
Temp_nodes = ["Connection", "Disconnection"]
for temp_node in Temp_nodes:
    G.add_node(temp_node)

# Add transitions between states with edge labels and conditions
G.add_edge("State_A_Standby", "Connection", label="Connection")
G.add_edge("Connection", "State_A", label="Connected vehicle")
G.add_edge("State_A", "State_B", label="Transition to State_B")
G.add_edge("State_B", "State_C", label="Transition to State_C, Switch k ON")
G.add_edge("State_C", "State_B", label="Transition to State_B, Switch k OFF")
G.add_edge("State_B", "State_A", label="Transition to State_A")
G.add_edge("State_C", "State_A", label="Transition to State_A")
G.add_edge("State_A", "Disconnection", label="Disconnect")
G.add_edge("State_B", "Disconnection", label="Disconnect")
G.add_edge("State_C", "Disconnection", label="Disconnect")
G.add_edge("Disconnection", "State_A_Standby", label="Disconnected vehicle")

# Draw the state machine diagram
pos = nx.spring_layout(G, seed=42)
nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True, node_size=1500, node_color='skyblue', font_size=10, font_weight='bold')
edge_labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'label')
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels=edge_labels, font_size=8)
plt.show()
```

So, you can run this code in python. it will show the state machine graph.

Now here, as you can see there are some edges between two same nodes like 'State_B' and 'State_C' and also the edge between 'State_C' to 'State_A'.

So, there are some cycles and loops possible in this state machine model.

I want to generate the every possible paths from this state machine between 'State_A' and 'Disconnect' nodes.

I have tried the below code to generate the each paths but it only generates the paths with only one way direction. But it does not include the cycles and loops.

```
all_possible_paths = []
# Using the inbuilt-function
all_paths = nx.all_simple_paths(G, source="State_A_Standby", target="Disconnection")
for path in all_paths:
    # Check if "Disconnection" is the end node
    if path[-1] == "Disconnection":
        # Replace "Disconnection" with the first node in the path
        path[-1] = path[0]

    # Remove temp nodes
    path = [node for node in path if node not in Temp_nodes]
    all_possible_paths.append(path)
    print("Processed Path:", path)
```

And if you can see the output from this code. You will see that it does not include all the edges. Some of the edges are still not included in these paths.

So, can anyone please help me here?

Comment: There are two edges between 'State_B' and 'State_C'

G.add_edge("State_B", "State_C", label="Transition to State_C, Switch k ON")
G.add_edge("State_C", "State_B", label="Transition to State_B, Switch k OFF")

Comment: If you can see again the code, 

There are total 2 pair of 'To and From' edges between 'State_A' and 'State_B' and between 'State_B' and 'State_C'. 

Four Edges are :-    

G.add_edge("State_A", "State_B", label="Transition to State_B")
G.add_edge("State_B", "State_C", label="Transition to State_C, Switch k ON")
G.add_edge("State_C", "State_B", label="Transition to State_B, Switch k OFF")
G.add_edge("State_B", "State_A", label="Transition to State_A")

Comment: I was confused.  When you talked about 'bidirectional' I thought you meant one edge that could be traversed in either direction.  I now realize you meant two states with two edges between them which go in opposite directions.

Comment: I still cannot see any edge between  State_A_Standby and State_A

Comment: I have figured it out. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Yen's Algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yen%27s_algorithm will give you every path between a source and destination node.

Perhaps your library has a method that implements this?

Unfortunately, the Wikipedia article's pseudo code has errors and ambiguities. So it is not so easy to roll your own.

FYI here is my own pseudo code for Yen's algorithm

```
IMPORT graph, source and sink
CLEAR vShortestPaths
calculate shortest path from source to sink, add to vShortestPaths
WHILE TRUE
   CLEAR vPotentialPaths
   SET work = graph
   LOOP PF over vShortestPaths
       LOOP spur over PF
            REMOVE out edge from spur in work used by PF
            calculate spurPath, shortest path from spur to sink in work
            IF spurPath exists
                CONTINUE to next iteration of LOOP spur
            SET newPath to combination of source to spur in PF and spurPath
            IF newPath NOT in vShortestPaths
                ADD newPath to vPotentialPaths
            END LOOP spur
        END LOOP PF
    IF vPotentialPaths NOT empty
        ADD shortest path in vPotentialPaths to vShortestPaths
    END WHILE TRUE
```

My C++ implementation can be found here https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder/blob/ee27d2393c0bb2700eba8198d4a4043124c63617/src/GraphTheory.cpp#L157-L220

---

Looking at the code you posted, here is the graph ( I have simplified the state names )

[image]

And here are all the paths between standbye and disconnect output by Yen's algorithm

```
standbye -> connection -> stateA -> disconnect
standbye -> connection -> stateA -> stateB -> disconnect
standbye -> connection -> stateA -> stateB -> stateC -> disconnect
```

Comment: Can you suggest me any other way please ?
Desired Output:
['State_A_Standby', 'State_A', 'State_B', 'State_C', 'State_B', 'State_A', 'State_A_Standby']
['State_A_Standby', 'State_A', 'State_B', 'State_C', 'State_B', 'State_A_Standby']
['State_A_Standby', 'State_A', 'State_B', 'State_C', 'State_A_Standby']
['State_A_Standby', 'State_A', 'State_B', 'State_A', 'State_A_Standby']
['State_A_Standby', 'State_A', 'State_B', 'State_A_Standby']
['State_A_Standby', 'State_A', 'State_A_Standby']

Comment: Yens' algorithm does what you want.  Have you tried it?

Comment: You wrote: Desired Output: ['State_A_Standby', 'State_A',  ... However, in the code you posted, there is no link between `State_A_Standby` and `State_A`

Comment: Yes, I have tried that out. 
Actually if you see the code and the code which I have posted later on, There are two nodes 'Connection' and 'Disconnection' which are temporary nodes. So, first I am drawing all the paths and then removing the 'Connection' node from all the paths and replacing the end node 'Disconnection' with the node 'State_A_Standby' in all the paths.

Comment: So, the actual output should be:
['State_A_Standby', 'Connection', 'State_A', 'State_B', 'State_C', 'State_B', 'State_A', 'Disconnection'] ['State_A_Standby', 'Connection', 'State_A', 'State_B', 'State_C', 'State_B', 'Disconnection'] ['State_A_Standby', 'Connection', 'State_A', 'State_B', 'State_C', 'Disconnection'] ['State_A_Standby', 'Connection', 'State_A', 'State_B', 'State_A', 'Disconnection'] ['State_A_Standby', 'Connection', 'State_A', 'State_B', 'Disconnection'] ['State_A_Standby', 'Connection', 'State_A', 'Disconnection']

Comment: That is very confusing.  I think you should decide whether you want to use the "temporary" nodes or not, then STICK TO THAT.  However you want to proceed you need to clarify your question because currently your example makes no sense.

Comment: With the code I have given first, the output should be: 
['State_A_Standby', 'Connection', 'State_A', 'State_B', 'State_C', 'State_B', 'State_A', 'Disconnection'] 
['State_A_Standby', 'Connection', 'State_A', 'State_B', 'State_C', 'State_B', 'Disconnection'] ['State_A_Standby', 'Connection', 'State_A', 'State_B', 'State_C', 'Disconnection'] ['State_A_Standby', 'Connection', 'State_A', 'State_B', 'State_A', 'Disconnection'] ['State_A_Standby', 'Connection', 'State_A', 'State_B', 'Disconnection'] 
['State_A_Standby', 'Connection', 'State_A', 'Disconnection']